# Are there any studies or research documenting how people react to change in UI?

Tags: changes

I recall seeing a new article ages back about a study someone did about how people react to changes in UI. The general conclusion was that no matter what you do, people will complain. Facebook was mentioned as a prime example.

I've lost this reference, however, and I was hoping to find it again to no avail. Does anyone remember this study, or even more generally, other research documenting how people react to website UI changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/cutting-edge-leadership/201109/why-facebook-s-recent-changes-outrage-people) is the article you are referring to?

> Lots of people are upset by the recent changes that Facebook made to its website. The look is a little different, and things function a little differently. This has caused people to rant and rave and some are even boycotting the site. What's going on?
>
> Actually, the reactions are a very common human response: We are very resistant to changes of any kind. Coca-Cola found out about this when the changed to the "New Coke" formula in 1985. It was a disaster primarily because consumers resisted the change. Coke was part of everyone's lives, and we begin to believe that the "traditional" the "tried and true" and "the way we've always done things around here" are the right way - the best way. And, we forcefully resist any changes to what we are used to.

Comment: That article is a bit low on experimental evidence...

Comment: I believe this is the article! But as PhillipW pointed out... not as much research backing it up as I thought I remembered. :\